# error during reformatvob

Tags: clearcase

I'm doing vob migration from Solaris to RHEL, out of 24 vobs 23 vobs migrated successfully except one pvob which is giving following error.

```
db_dumper.54: Error: Unexpected error from database library (8) in "../db__dump.c" line 2835
db_dumper.54: Error: Error from libdb (8)
cleartool: Error: Could not dump database.
cleartool: Error: Trouble dumping versioned object base "/vobstg/pvob.vbs".

dbcheck status,

Processing delete chain: 0 records on delete chain.
Processing records:
100%

Database consistency check completed

0 errors were encountered in 0 records/nodes

Check for HyperSlink and got following error cleartool checkvob -hlinks -hltype hltype:HyperSlink vob:/vob/pvob

cleartool: Error: Hyperlink type not found: "HyperSlink".
```

Stuck in the migration

Comment: I have included a reference to your IBM support thread in the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can help knowing at what stage the `dp_dumb` was before exiting in error, like in [this thread](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=14271243).

But the usual course of action is to compressed a **locked** pvob content, and send it to IBM for analysis.
The [HyperSlinks](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21123438) aren't an issue here (as they would when [making a replica](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21228213)).

As mention in this [IBM support thread](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=14689069):

> IBM support resolved this, **one of the activity had spacial character which caused this**. Now reformat vob works.
>   Yet to start the sync with master site.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with special character in activity, IBM gave me tool to fix it. Now things are normal.